# Get the speaker notes from embeding

Tags: javascript, html, flask, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am builiding a website for slide teaching based on Google Slides. However, i cannot get the speaker notes from slides.
As the figure below, i created a html website including "get speaker notes" button and a text box with slide frame. Then when i click on "get speaker notes" it should put out speaker notes into textbox, but it didn't.

[Image of system](https://imgtr.ee/image/CUOhb)

I dont really know how to get text as speaker notes from frame as google slides. Is there any way? Thanks!

I tried to resolve cross-origin issues, but it still occurs